# How to use or calculate DecodePixelWidth of BitmapImage properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, richtextbox, flowdocument

Trying to understand **WPF** and work with images. I have **RichTextBox** with 665 width. For example I am loading image (5400x2700, 32bits, 96dpi). I thought that I should do something like that:

1. Convert to physical pixels. I know that my monitor have 100.13 DPI. So **[Physical Unit Size]** = **[Device-Independent Unit Size]** * **[Monitor DPI]** = 1/96 * 100.13 = 1.04
2. Convert **RichTextBox** width to physical pixels: **[RichTextBox width]** * **[Physical Unit Size]** = 665 * 1.04 ≈ 700
3. `bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.StreamSource = memorystream;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 700;
    bitmap.EndInit();`

But If I set `bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 1900`, then image will be clearer.
[image: Two images with different DecodePixelWidth]

How to set **DecodePixelWidth** properly?

Comment: Why do you think you should set it at all?

Comment: @Clemens To save significant application memory